# Email activation link issue in Django 3.1.3

Tags: python, django

Well, I decided to implement an account authentication system by sending an activation link to the email of the user who just registered and here are the views and the message sent

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
            message = render_to_string(
                'users/email_template.html',
                {
                    'user': user,
                    'domain': current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                }
            )
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
 

 def activate(request, uidb64, token):
     try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
     except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
     if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login account.')
     else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

Token Generator class:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
 from six import text_type


 class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
       def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
           return (
               text_type(user.pk) + text_type(timestamp) +
               text_type(user.is_active)
           )

 account_activation_token = TokenGenerator()
```

The template with the message:

```
 {% autoescape off %}
     Hi {{ user.username }},
     Please click on the link to confirm your registration

     http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
 {% endautoescape %}
```

url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path("profile/<str:username>/", views.profile, name="profile"),
]
```

Everything is working fine, but there is a problem with the activation link, it appears like this: **http://localhost:8000//users/activate/MTY/agxxit-58f6e97c157ac2855dd80794f2ce9c62/** with two bars after port 8000, which is generate an error, to work I need to edit the link in the browser bar, removing one of the bars. Does anyone know how to organize this link so that it does not appear with the two bars after port 8000?

Comment: Heya - what does your urls.py configuration look like? Wondering if you might have an extra slash in there.

Comment: I forgot to post the url configuration. Just a moment, I'll edit

Comment: @Joaquim, Did it help you? Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your domain name must be "**www.example.com**" without any slashes.

From Django: **[domain](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.models.Site.domain)** - The fully qualified domain name associated with the website. For example, `www.example.com`.

So change site **domain** via `/admin/sites/site/`

In your case it should be: **localhost:8000**

Comment: @Joaquim, happy to help .

Answer (score 0):

from django doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) you can use

```
request.build_absolute_uri("/activate/%s/%s/" %(uid,token)
```